# Spring validation can't find message

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I have a problem with the validation in SpringMVC, it can't find my error messages...
I have an error that says:  `No message found under code 'empty' for locale 'en_GB'.` also if it is configured in my *messages.properties*.

I have it configured in the spring context for the servlet:

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename">
            <beans:value>WEB-INF/classes/messages</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

In my project the file is under *src/main/resources/messages.properties*, and it is:

```
empty.user.password=Il campo password non può essere lasciato vuoto
empty.user.username=Il campo username non può essere lasciato vuoto
unique.user.username=L''username {0} è già usato
empty=Il campo non può essere vuoto
```

Then I have a validator:

```
@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    final User user = (User) target;
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "username", "empty");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password", "empty");
    if (userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) != null){
        errors.rejectValue("username", "unique", new Object[]{user.getUsername()}, "The username already exists");
    }
}
```

And in my JSP:

```
<form:errors path="*" cssClass="alert error" element="div" />
```

I can't figure out what can be the problem...

UPDATE:
I noticed that deploying the application in a Tomcat inside Eclipse it works...it has problem just when I execute it using maven with both `jetty:run` and `tomcat:run`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your messages.prop file is getting copied over under classes directory

HTH

Comment: I didn't checked it, but I don't think this is the problem, 'cause for other messages it works...